# select query runs slow in production but faster in staging - oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Here's the issue.

I'm using Oracle 11g Database.

I have a master table that has rows in lacs and is in use almost the entire working day. We have a monthly activity where we dump all production data into staging(testing) db. Now whenever I execute a select query to retrieve data of consumer based on a their address, the time taken on staging db is 3 seconds and 50-60 seconds on production server. All the necessary indexes are in place. No issues in the procedures being called. Stats have been gathered. Indexes have been rebuilt.

I need to know the following:

1. Is it because that the table on production is busy the entire day?
2. Does it have anything to do with buffer cache or any other database parameter?

Also, I would like to mention that we use the "LIKE" operator in where condition to search consumer based on a particular address. However, we are also using % as a prefix i.e. for example, select * from master_table where m_address like '%variable_name%'. Now I have read that Oracle might omit the use of index if the % wildcard is used as prefix i.e. before the character. However, the astonishing factor is that it runs perfectly fine on my Testing environment as previously mentioned.

Pl help. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Get execution plan traces for all environments and see if there is a difference (in the query plan or in the buffer gets that they cause).

Comment: As Thilo said, you need to get execution plan to analyze your query.Without getting, it is hard to say a solution.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the execution plans shows the same results on all environments.